# Libgdx and gradle modules

Tags: gradle, module, libgdx

I have an standard libGDX project setup with Gradle (only targeting desktop). It is a client-server application but currently all the code is under the core/ module. Right now I have 3 main package: common, client and server. Obviously client and server need the code under common. I would like to create a jar only with the client and another jar only with the server so that my server code cannot be reverse engineered. How should I do that ? What is the best practice considering the default structure from libGDX project ?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [unofficial gdx-setup.jar](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-setup) which can (among other things) generate a "server" module automatically, in addition to the usual modules (core, desktop, etc). This lets you build a separate server jar if desired. You could try creating a test project using the gdx-setup.jar linked above, and take a look at the gradle files to see how they're structured. Alternatively, you could create a new project and then migrate your existing source files and assets to the new project, though this may be more trouble than the other path.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look to this repo. Does this means that the right way to have a jar contening only the client code is to create another module on the root folder ? Or is there a way to split my module inside the core module itself. Something like submodules ?

Comment: Creating sub-modules might be the best way. Another thing you could do is have the Game object (made in the core module) take in an additional object of some kind, and have desktop and server each provide a different implementation of the object. Not sure how feasible that would be though.